# How to configure Media Codec AAC Decoder (Audio sent with Gstreamer)

Tags: android, gstreamer, audio-streaming, android-mediacodec, aac

I want to build an app that plays AAC audio stream sent by my **Raspberry Pi** with **Gstreamer**. This is the pipeline I set in Gstreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! faac "bitrate=64000" ! "audio/mpeg, mpegversion=4, rate = 44100, channels = 1" ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux! udpsink host=224.0.0.1 port=8001
```

It encodes the audio data in AAC LC as mp4 with a bitrate of 64000, a sample rate of 44100 and 1 channel in a mpeg ts container.

I set my decoder with the following code:

```
format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 44100);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64 * 1024);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_IS_ADTS, 1);

byte[] bytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x11, (byte)0x90};
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", bb);
```

I also tried it without the `MediaFormat.KEY_IS_ADTS` line. (same error)

This is what my decoder looks like:

```
while (!stopTrack) {


    multicastSocket.receive(packet);

    decoder.start();
    data = packet.getData();

    inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
    outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
    inputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);

    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
    {
        inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        inputBuffer.clear();

        inputBuffer.put(data);

        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0);
    }

    bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

    while (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
    {
        outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

        outputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
        outputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);

        outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
        outputBuffer.get(outData);

        Log.d("AudioDecoder", outData.length + " bytes decoded");

        track.write(outData, 0, outData.length);

        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
        outputBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
W/SoftAAC2: aacDecoder_DecodeFrame decoderErr = 0x4004
W/SoftAAC2: AAC decoder returned error 0x4004, substituting silence
I/SoftAAC2: Reconfiguring decoder: 0->48000 Hz, 0->0 channels
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-374583
```

If I save the incoming data to a file it is playable! So the problem must be the decoder.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried playing the stream from vlc like udp://@224.0.0.1:8001 it works for me with this pipe `audiotestsrc ! voaacenc bitrate=64000 ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=224.0.0.1 port=8001` - but thats on gst 1.6.3 .. I have no experience with mediacodec

Comment: I tried it and it worked, so the problem must be the mediacodec. But thanks for your answer!